# Does rotten food produce methane gas?

Tags: food-chemistry

If we put a meal into the food storage container, does it produce methane gas while it is getting rotten or what else types of gases it produce?

Comment: Food hardly rots  by itself but is decomposed by organisms, such as bacteria and others. What gases will be produced depends on what food it is, what "microbes" digest it and, at what temperature and if there is oxygen present.  I guess your question is not specific enough to get a satisfying answer.